# Loading Tab Content With Ajax Call

Tags: javascript

I have a tab control that loads the content via $().load() and then the page loaded will load data from a json call to a server.  I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to go about this.

Basically I'm wondering the best way to load tab content which will contain another ajax call to get json data.  I'm thinking all these ajax calls will hinder performance.

```
$("#tab-about").click(function () {
     $("#tab-content").load("/about");
     /* about content will then have it's own ajax call for json data */
});
```

Comment: Then consolidate your requests so your initial tab load is pre-populated and only when changes are required will you make the second call. Sometimes the complication of doing this isn't worth it and you go ahead and allow the double AJAX requests. It's a trade-off you'll have to evaluate yourself.

Comment: I was trying to see if there is a simple way but it might be worth considering angularjs or emberjs to accomplish this.

Comment: I actually decided to load the json data first and in the call back, execute the .load to load page/template which I can then populate the data in.  At least this way, the data is already available when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue depends on your project.But the code can become buggy.
Make sure to put the second ajax call in setTimeout because it may not called when you upload your website.Try this :

```
setTimeout(function(){ /*Your code for ajax load content */   },0);
```

Function in setTimeout will run after its containing function finished.